# Update set and write to Csv

Tags: python, csv, set

Im having an issue getting the set too write to csv how I would like it too. The reason It is a set and not a list because is it goes through a couple years and a person will be listed multiple times. The error is `Error: iterable expected, not int`

I would like to have the csv write like this:

```
SkaterId | Full Name  |
_______________________   
  845756 | John Smith |
_______________________
  878734 | Jim John   |
```

Script:

```
import csv
import requests

req = requests.get('http://www.nhl.com/stats/rest/skaters?isAggregate=false&reportType=basic&isGame=false&reportName=bios'
                   '&sort=[{%22property%22:%22playerLastName%22,%22direction%22:%22ASC%22}]&cayenneExp=gameTypeId=2%20and'
                   '%20seasonId%3E=20092010%20and%20seasonId%3C=20172018') 
data = req.json()['data']

player_info = set()

for info in data:
    fullname = info['playerName']
    first_name = info['playerFirstName']
    last_name = info['playerLastName']
    skater_id = info['playerId']
    shoots = info['playerShootsCatches']
    pos  = info['playerPositionCode']
    player_info.update([skater_id,fullname])

    print(skater_id,fullname)
print(player_info)

headers = ["skater_id", "fullname"]

with open('NHL_PlayerInfo.csv', "w", newline='') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    writer.writerow(headers)
    writer.writerows(player_info)
f.close()
```

Comment: Use `player_info.add` instead of `player_info.update` when adding to the set. `set.update` will iterate through the given argument and add each element of that said argument. Make sure to use `tuples` instead of `lists`. Also, you don't need `f.close()` since using `with` takes care of that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue stems from `writer.writerows` and it is because by the time you're done with your for loop, the contents of `player_info` are just a combination of integers and strings (skater ID's and full names). However, `writer.writerows` actually expects a sequence of sequences, like a `set` of `tuples`.

What you thought you were getting was a `set` of `lists`, but that's not the case because of the line `player_info.update([skater_id,fullname])`. This line of code actually doesn't add the list to the set but, instead, it adds each element of the list to the set.

What you should use is `player_info.add((skater_id, fullname))`. The `add` method on the set adds the `tuple` to your set, and not element by element adding.

The following is a tweaked version of your code:

```
import csv
import requests


req = requests.get('http://www.nhl.com/stats/rest/skaters?isAggregate=false&reportType=basic&isGame=false&reportName=bios'
                   '&sort=[{%22property%22:%22playerLastName%22,%22direction%22:%22ASC%22}]&cayenneExp=gameTypeId=2%20and'
                   '%20seasonId%3E=20092010%20and%20seasonId%3C=20172018') 
data = req.json()['data']

player_info = set()

for info in data:
    fullname = info['playerName']
    first_name = info['playerFirstName']
    last_name = info['playerLastName']
    skater_id = info['playerId']
    shoots = info['playerShootsCatches']
    pos  = info['playerPositionCode']
    player_info.add((skater_id, fullname))

    print(skater_id,fullname)
print(player_info)

headers = ["skater_id", "fullname"]

with open('NHL_PlayerInfo.csv', "w", newline="", encoding="utf8") as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)
    writer.writerow(headers)
    writer.writerows(player_info)
```

I hope this helps.

Answer (score 0):

Change the line

```
player_info.update([skater_id,fullname])
```

to

```
player_info.add((skater_id,fullname))
```

and it will work.

The `update` function creates a set from the list you pass then adds their elements to "player_info". So, your final set will contain all the `skater_id` and  `fullname` as the elements of `player_info` set.

As I understand, you want to have a `skater_id` and the corresponding `fullname` as one element in the set. So, create a tuple of each combination and then add to the set. Hope it helps.